# Can anyone solve with this circuit the problem is with resistor in series with diode?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, diodes

[image]Can anyone solve this problem ?? 
I want vout analysis

The output is in green ?
Why the capacitor voltage is -10 from vout to node above vin ?? In first negative cycle the current will move anticlock wise so it was supposed that capacitor has +ve 10 charge from right while in reality havent been ?
[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question

Comment: @Marla can you explain the output ?

Comment: what is `node above vin`?   .... if you are going to talk about nodes, then please label the nodes ... `A`, `B`, `C`, etc

Comment: @jsotola i mean from right side of capacitor to its left side

Comment: change the input period from 1 ms to 1 hour ... what voltages would you see and when would you see those voltages?

Comment: @AhmedEhab Probably the diode was put in backwards. Or the two points used for your green measurement is backwards.